# Microsoft CA, Automatic issue

Tags: certificate, pki, pfx

Does anybody know if it's possible to issue several certificates from a CSV like this:

```
CN=TestCertificate1, DNS=testServer1
CN=TestCertificate2, DNS=testServer2
CN=TestCertificate3, DNS=testServer3
```

Using a given template and getting a pfx as output?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable, although not by simply uploading a .CSV file and downloading the output.  The easiest way would be to use some of the [PKI Client Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848636.aspx).  These are PowerShell commands that let you interact with a Microsoft CA from a script or the command line.

The first step, would be to generate a certificate request using the DN information you find in the .CSV file.  A great tutorial on generating the CSR can be [found here](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/18638).  Once the certificates have been approved on the CA, you can export them using the relevant PKI Client Cmdlet, `Export-PfxCertificate` via your PowerShell script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Shadowman! Now I am stuck on exporting all the certificates I managed to issue remotely. For some reason I cant use the Export-PfxCertificate if I am not in Windows 8, -even though I am running PS 4.0-